# How Do I Combine these different codes to work together

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, formatting

I am embarrassed to say this is my weak spot in SQL Server, I cannot figure out how to get this code to function properly. It is a few different codes in one:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN RRDD Not Like '12%' AND RRDD Not Like '13%' AND RRDD Not Like '16%' AND RRDD
Not Like '17%' AND RRDD Not Like '2706%' AND RRDD Not Like '2707%' AND RRDD Not Like '2331%'
THEN CAST([2011 Total] AS FLOAT)*CASE WHEN IsNumeric [DUR_In_Hours] = 1 THEN
CAST([DUR_IN_Hours] AS FLOAT) ELSE 0 END) AS SP_DOM_COST
```

The error I am getting is the following:

`IsNumeric is not recognized and incorrect syntax near DUR_In_Hours`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing parentheses for `IsNumeric()`:

```
 WHEN IsNumeric([DUR_In_Hours]) = 1
```

You are also missing the `END` on your first `CASE`:

```
SUM(CASE 
        WHEN RRDD Not Like '12%' 
            AND RRDD Not Like '13%' 
            AND  RRDD Not Like '16%' 
            AND RRDD Not Like '17%' 
            AND RRDD Not Like '2706%' 
            AND RRDD Not Like '2707%' 
            AND RRDD Not Like '2331%' 
        THEN CAST([2011 Total] AS FLOAT)
        ELSE 0
        END
    *
    CASE 
        WHEN IsNumeric([DUR_In_Hours]) = 1 
        THEN CAST([DUR_IN_Hours] AS FLOAT) 
        ELSE 0 
        END) AS SP_DOM_COST
```

One last suggestion, depending on the datatype of the `RRDD` field you might not need to use the `LIKE` syntax. You might be able to replace that with `NOT IN`:

```
SUM(CASE 
        WHEN RRDD NOT IN ('12', '13', '16', '17', '2706', '2707', '2331')
        THEN CAST([2011 Total] AS FLOAT)
        ELSE 0
        END
    * 
     CASE 
        WHEN IsNumeric([DUR_In_Hours]) = 1 
        THEN CAST([DUR_IN_Hours] AS FLOAT) 
        ELSE 0 
        END) AS SP_DOM_COST
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/489ba/4)

Comment: Which only makes me more embarrassed. I made the corrections and it still says unable to parse query text

Comment: @Andrew what is the datatype of `RRDD`?

Comment: @Andrew did you include the `ELSE 0 `?

Comment: Yes I did include the ELSE 0

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure what the issue is, this code is working on sql fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/489ba/4.  Can you update this with your table structure and some sample data?